# Trouble with basic math in JS

Tags: javascript, html

Why does my `x = 0, x++` add up by 1, 2, then 4, 8, 16, etc.
I want it to add up by 1 each time

```js
    let x = 0;
    function startTime(){
      x++;
      document.getElementById("startP").innerHTML = x;
      setInterval(startTime, 1000);    
    }
```

```html
<p id="startP">-</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an recursion here. `setInterval` runs forever until you stop it manually. With each interval you starting a new interval.

`The setInterval() method will continue calling the function until clearInterval() is called, or the window is closed`

See the definition: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

You are pribably looking for `setTimeout()`

Comment: you sir deserve to be knighted.  thank you so much, i knew it was something simple. Saved me a lot of stress!

Answer (score 0):

You should use setTimeout instead of setInterval.  This is because setTimeout will call once; and setInterval will keep calling.